# Nginx, serving routes following the / results in a 404 not found page

Tags: nginx

My local nginx serves the home page (`index.php`) just fine using:

`http://userauthapi.local`

When I try to use other routes i.e. `http://userauthapi.local/foobar`  I get the 404 page.

My server block looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ;

    root /var/www/userauthapi.local/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name userauthapi.local www.userauthapi.local;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return view('test here');
});
```

Nothing found in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

```
2024/01/14 12:46:02 [notice] 7459#7459: using inherited sockets from "5;6;"
```

Can you see anything obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the server block was incorrect. Should be:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name userauthapi.local;
    root /var/www/userauthapi.local/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```